# How to disable appearance change events in WPF?

Tags: wpf, color-scheme, appearance

In Windows Vista whenever we change the appearance from display properties, it is forcing recreation of the windows controls in our application. Is there a way we can disable this events at application level? BTW our application needs to have consistent look and feel across different themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app needs to have a consistent look regardless of what theme is set in the OS, then you probably need to re-style everything at the application level so that the default theme styles are overridden.

[ControlTemplate Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) should be a good place to start.